# Add custom headers to HTTP 401 responses from Kerberos mod_auth_kerb

Tags: apache-2.2, kerberos, http-headers, http-authentication, mod-auth-kerb

I'm using Apache with [mod_auth_kerb](http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/) to perform HTTP authentication. How do I add custom headers to the 401 Authorization Required response generated by the auth module?

The relevant sections of my Apache configuration are below. My custom header is being added after the `Require valid-user` check passes but is ignored on the initial request when the server generates HTTP 401 response.

```
<Location /app/login>
    AuthType Kerberos
    ...

    Require valid-user
    ErrorDocument 401 /redirect-page.html
</Location>

...

<LocationMatch /app/login>
    Header always set X-My-Header my-value
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `ErrorDocument 401` line. This changed the `REQUEST_URI` to "/redirect-page.html", which meant that my `<LocationMatch>` no longer applied. I modified this tag to include both the URL of the login page as well as that of the error document and now things works as expected.